# Why do we need to specify the number of flash wait cycles?

Tags: stm32, cortex-m

Especially when working with "faster" devices like STMF4xx/F7xx we need to specify the number of flash wait cycles, based on the supply voltage and the sys-clock frequency.

When the CPU fetches instructions/or constants this is done over the FLITF. Am I right with the assumption that the FLITF holds a CPU request as long as it can provide the requested data, making it impossible for other Bus-Masters to access flash meanwhile.

If this was true, why should it be important to any interface to know flash wait cycles. Like Cache does preload instructions so or so, independent if it knows how long to wait, no?

Comment: you will/should find that the flash isnt the only logic in some/many mcu's that have speed limits.  some will tell you that the peripheral clock cannot exceed X even though the cpu can do well beyond that. PLLs in particular have min and max ranges that you must use otherwise you may end up with an unstable clock (could never lock or go out of lock and  just hang, depends on the design).  Just because some cars can go 200mph doesnt mean all of them can.  for each logic block or peripheral for each chip you have to keep the timing within the designed parameters or bad things can happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the flash interface isn't magic.

It has to meet the necessary setup and hold times for addressing and reading out the flash cells, which will vary somewhat depending on voltage. Taking the STM32F411 as an example (because I have that TRM handy), doing some maths with the voltage/frequency/wait-state table implies that a read from flash on one of those takes in the order of ~30ns above 2.7V, down to ~60ns below 2.1V.

Since the flash interface doesn't have its own asynchronous nanosecond-precision timekeeping ability (because that would be needlessly complicated, power-hungry, and silly), that translates to asserting its signals for *n* clock cycles, after which it can assume the data signals from the cells are stable enough to read back<sup>*</sup>. How does it know what the clock frequency is, and therefore what *n* should be? Simple: you, as the programmer who set the clock, tell it. Some hardware things are just infinitely easier to let software deal with.

<sub>* and *then* going through the further shenanigans of extracting the relevant 8, 16 or 32 bits out of the 128-bit line it's read, to finally spit *that* out the other side onto the AHB bus to the waiting CPU, obviously.</sub>

Comment: Helped me a lot. Just to finish this, the "only" thing we risk, is to get corrupted data if we don't care about wait cycles?

Comment: Probably, but I wouldn't bet anything valuable on it. It's not beyond the realms of possibility that there could be some control signals which could get into an undefined state and lead to something going haywire or deadlocking. And it's not as if executing not-necessarily-correct instructions is likely to be at all "safe" either way.

Comment: I have experience with ST's internal flashes with incorrect wait state settings, and even being off by one will cause problems that will be very difficult to track down. Even if you shave off a wait state below what they specify. It may work at room temperature, but then start failing when colder or hotter. Once you find out that the flash was configured incorrectly, everything makes sense, but before then you'll go crazy trying to track down a problem in all the wrong places.